# Wait for the UI to redraw before "taking a screenshot" of it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

### The challenge

I'm trying to create a Window that'll draw a card on a page of a PDF document.

The idea is to receive a `collection` (of the items that should be drawn on the card), then go through them, and for each of the items, load it to a `UniformGrid` (to give the impression of a actual card), capture an image of the screen and draw it to a page of a PDF document.

So far so good.

### What I've tried (and partially succeeded)

Here's what I've tried:

(the following code was added to a `Loaded` event handler of the window)

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// This is just an example
int[][] items = new int[10][];

// Fill the matrix

foreach (int[] array in items)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // uGrid is an UniformGrid
        uGrid.Children.Clear();

        foreach (int id in array)
        {
            Border child = null;

            // Create child element and add it to the Uniform Grid

            uGrid.Children.Add(child);
        }
    });

    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        // Draws an image of 'this' to the PDFDocument 'document'
        PdfHelper.DrawPictureOfControlToPdf(document, this);

        // DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle here is responsible for executing the DrawPicture method only after the uGrid has been redrawed
    }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);

}

// This will save the PDF on your documents folder
document.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "MyTestPDF.pdf"));
```

#### A full (but very short, I promise) working example can be found [on my GitHub](https://github.com/schdck/CaptureScreenToPdfSample)

Also, the produced PDFs (when debugging and when not - see problem below), can be found [here](https://github.com/schdck/CaptureScreenToPdfSample/tree/master/CaptureScreenToPdf/PDFs)

### The problem

The above code works great ***when on debugging mode***.

- When debugging: the code runs without errors, the PDF is created with the correct number of pages, and the cards are correctly drawn on it.
- When not: the code runs without errors, the PDF is created with the correct number of pages, but the cards are not drawn on it.

---

I think that what's causing the issue is the `DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle` on the following piece of code:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    PdfHelper.DrawPictureOfControlToPdf(document, this);

}), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
```

It should indicate that the `Action` must only be run when the `UniformGrid` finished redrawing (or after the Dispatcher took care of it, more precisely). But apparently this only works inside debugging mode.

Does someone know how to solve this?

If not, is there any alternative that I'm not thinking of?

**@EDIT**

I don't think this is important, but I'm using [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) to generate/handle the PDF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all `Dispatcher.Invoke` in your code (they are not doing anything good here), and then call

```
this.UpdateLayout();
```

to force redraw of current control, before calling `PdfHelper.DrawPictureOfControlToPdf(document, this);`.